# pivot data is not passed to Laravel 10 job

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I have many to many relationship between model A and model B with pivot data.

so in model A

```
  public function modelbs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ModelB::class)->withTimestamps()->withPivot([
            'pivot_data_1',
        ]);
    }
```

and in model B

```
  public function modelas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ModelA::class)->withTimestamps()->withPivot([
            'pivot_data_1',
        ]);
    }
```

everything is working fine, but i have a schedule command that runs and passes the relationship to a job

```
$modelAs = ModelA::with('modelbs')->get();
foreach ($modelAs as $modelA){
   foreach ($modelA->modelbs as $modelB) 
      {
        GetSomethingJob::dispatch($modelA, $modelB);
       }

}
```

before the job dispatch, i can see and access the pivot data.

and inside my job construct

```
public ModelA $modela;
public ModelB $modelb;
public function __construct($modela, $modelb)
{
    dd($modelb);
    $this->modela=$modela;
    $this->modelb=$modelb;
     dd($this->modelb);
}
```

and here i can also see the pivot data (for both dd() in top )

but when the job gets called and queue works, i only get the service without the pivot data.

is there an extra settings that i should do to tell laravel to get me the the same service i have saved already

i am expecting to get the pivot data that are passed in the first time i made the call to the job dispatch

Comment: Can you share the handle method from the command, if you can access it in constructor then should be accessed through out the class

Comment: public function handle(): void
    {
        dd($this->modelb);
}

i can;t see the pivot data here

Comment: The queue is an independent job, and the dispatched job executes neither the original Request nor the Session.

Comment: Your preload data by `with` won't exists when job executing, it will construct a new query by the model you passed to re-query the data.

Comment: You can reload the pivot data in handle by `$this->model->load('modelbs');`.

Comment: yea i got that it's different and it's loading that specific record ( modelb ) only without pivot data, my question is if there's any option to use to let laravel know that i want it to get the pivot data, not only that specific record

Comment: No, jobs have separate pids. Most of the time the job is executed, the original process has been closed. To be more specific, the job will have an independent app instance.

Comment: The only thing that is relevant to the job is the original data you passed in. If you accept it, you can try to convert the incoming model data into an array, example `GetSomethingJob::dispatch($modelA->toArray(), $modelB);`.